# want to get cpeDeliveryDate,cpeShippedDate equipmentShipped partDescription columns from the below list of dictionary using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I want to get `cpeDeliveryDate`, `cpeShippedDate`, `equipmentShipped` and `partDescription` columns from a list of dictionaries using pandas:

```py
[
    {
        "cpeDeliveryDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 10, 9, 38, 15),
        "cpeShippedDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 9, 15, 19, 3),
        "equipmentShipped": [
            {
                "partDescription": "CABLE CAT5E ETHERNET PATCH CABLE SNAGLESS 6FT YELLOW AT1506-EVYL ALEN",
                "partRequestNumber": "2100406532",
            },
            {
                "partDescription": "NETWORK APPLIANCE VERSA810 ANA 1+1PSU FWA3260A1703E-T ADVANTECH CORPORATION",
                "serialNumber": "KSA5584532",
                "partRequestNumber": "2100406532",
            },
            {
                "partDescription": "NETWORK APPLIANCE VERSA810 ANA 1+1PSU FWA3260A1703E-T ADVANTECH CORPORATION",
                "serialNumber": "KSA5584554",
                "partRequestNumber": "2100406532",
            },
        ],
        "cpeTrackingNumber": "1ZRV61280142707845",
        "cpeShippingAddress": "W234N2091 RIDGEVIEW PARKWAY CT, WAUKESHA, WISCONSIN, UNITED STATES, 53188",
        "proofOfDelivery": "MANNY",
        "shippingCarrier": "UPS",
    }
]
```